# Material-ui responsive drawer click the listitem and toggle (close) the drawer on mobile drawer only

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/k2o6jz5o87

How can responsive drawer click the listitem and toggle (close) the drawer on mobile drawer only.

I tried

```
        <ListItem
          button
          key={text}
          // i added this line
          onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={text} />
        </ListItem>
```

But it toggle the drawer on desktop viewpoint too.

Answer (score 0):

I think U can check current width of windows, if width < 768px (mobile), U can disable drawer

```
class WindowWidth extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      displayDrawer: true
    };
    this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.width);
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
  updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({
      displayDrawer: window.innerWidth < 768
    });

  }
  render() {
    const {displayDrawer} = this.state;
    return (
      <ListItem
      button
      key={text}
      // i added this line
      onClick={displayDrawer ? this.handleDrawerToggle : function(){}}
    >
      <ListItemIcon>
        {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={text} />
    </ListItem>
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
}
```